# Using Rails Associations in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, associations, haml

Im trying to create a feed using ajax and rails that gets the activities of admins and alerts. When I first created the view I used rails only, but decided I wanted to have a feed that updates every time there is a new activity in the database using ajax. My ajax function works and everything, however i realized that I had alot of associations that I couldnt call because it was javascript not rails. I was wondering how I could use a join to replace the id of query to the username of person who created the alert like activity.alert.username

action: "has created alert"
admin_id: null
alert_id: 17
category: "Alert"
created_at: "2015-05-13T04:12:47.862Z"
id: 6
school_id: 1
updated_at: "2015-05-13T04:12:47.862Z"

```
class ActivitiesController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :authenticate_admin!
    def index
        @activities = Activity.where(:school_id => current_admin.school.id).order("created_at DESC").limit(20)
        respond_to do |format|
            format.json { render json: @activities}
            format.html 
        end
    end
end
```

Old View

```
- @activities.each do |activity|
    %div.panel.panel-default
        %div.panel-body
            - if activity.admin_id != nil
                %span.action
                    = activity.admin.email
                    = activity.action
            - else
                %span.action
                    = activity.alert.user.username
                    = activity.action

            %span.timestamp
                #{activity.created_at.strftime("%b %d %Y %l:%M %p")}
            %span.category
                #{activity.category}
```

New View

```
%div#activity-feed

:javascript

    getActivity();

    function getActivity(){

        $.getJSON("activity", function(data) {

            for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
                var feed = "<div class='panel panel-default'> <div class='panel-body'>" + "<span>" + data[i].action + "</span>" + "</div> </div>";
            }

            $("#activity-feed").html(feed);

                    console.log(data);

        });
    }

    setInterval(function() {
        getActivity();
    }, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle data associations in the controller (i.e. Rails), as Rails is the layer that has access to the database directly. Basically, what you want to do is to load all the necessary data from the database in the controller, and send it back to the client (Javascript) for it to consume.

You can use "include" to include associated objects along.

```
@activities = Activity.include(:alert).where...
```

Comment: yes thats what I was wondering how to implement the join to do just that

Comment: I just updated the answer. You can use include. I hope this helps.

Comment: it still gives me the id not the username